# toString() not working with super and sub classes

Tags: java, arrays, loops, overriding, tostring

I am having an issue getting my toString() method to display properly. I have it overloaded in each of my subclasses and I am calling for it in the main method. I get the beginning of the desired output, but afterwards all I get is a hash. I am also trying to display the results of the array as well using this toString() method.

```
    //main method

    public class PublicationArray
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Publication[] publications = new Publication[10];

  publications[0] = new Magazine("American Fisherman", 2.0, 100);      
  publications[1] = new Book("C++ Programming", 25.0, 70);
  publications[2] = new Magazine("Time", 1.5, 100);
  publications[3] = new Book("Morning Dove", 15.0, 39);
  publications[4] = new Magazine("Nerd", 3.0, 10);
  publications[5] = new Book("Walking and Chewing Gum for Dummies",14.0,40);
  publications[6] = new Magazine("New Yorker", 2.25, 28);
  publications[7] = new Book("J++ Programming", 30.0, 55);
  publications[8] = new Magazine("Devorced", 1.75, 33);
  publications[9] = new Book("Doing Nothing for Dummies", 10.0, 10);

  for(int i = 0; i < publications.length; i++)
  {
     System.out.println("Publication [" + i + "] is " + publications.toString());
  }


}
}


   //one of the subclasses, the other is identical except for the formula

public class Magazine extends Publication
{
public Magazine(String title, double cost, int quantity)
{
  super(title, cost, quantity);
}

String month;

public void setMonth(String pubMonth)
{
  month = pubMonth;
}
@Override
public double setPrice()
{
  double price = cost * 1.6;
  return price;
} 

@Override
public String toString()
{
  String display = "Title " + title + ",Price " + setPrice() +
     ", Cost " + cost + ", Quantity " + quantity;
  return display;
}
}



//Output

Publication [0] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [1] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [2] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [3] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [4] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [5] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [6] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [7] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [8] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0
Publication [9] is Title ,Price 0.0, Cost 0.0, Quantity 0

public abstract class Publication
{
String title = "";
double cost;
int quantity;

//Constructor
public Publication(String pubTitle, double pubCost, int pubQuantity)
{
  pubTitle = title;
  pubCost = cost;
  pubQuantity = quantity;
} 

//Set Methods
public void setTitle(String pubTitle)
{
  title = pubTitle;
}
public void setCost(double pubCost)
{
  cost = pubCost;
}
public void setQuantity(int pubQuantity)
{
  quantity = pubQuantity;
}

//Get Methods
public String getTitle()
{
  return title;
}
public double getCost()
{
  return cost;
}
public int getQuantity()
{
  return quantity;
}

public abstract double setPrice();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because using the `toString()` method on an array gives you the memory address of that array. You want to be using `Arrays.toString(publications)` in your custom `toString()` method.

Also, you are looping through to display every object in your array, but printing the whole array instead of a single instance:

```
for(int i = 0; i < publications.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Publication [" + i + "] is " + publications[i].toString());
}
```

For your issue of your output only being zeroes, make sure the variables in the super class are `protected` or `public`. then in your subclass' `toString()` method access them using the `this` keyword:

```
public String toString()
{
    String display = "Title " + this.title + ",Price " + setPrice() + ", Cost " + this.cost + ", Quantity " + this.quantity;
    return display;
}
```

You should also use the `this` keyword to access `cost` in your `setPrice()` method.

**EDIT:**

The issue of getting zeroes as output is likely due to your constructor in your `Publication` class. You are assigning your variables the wrong way around. It should look like this:

```
public Publication(String pubTitle, double pubCost, int pubQuantity)
{
    title = pubTitle;
    cost = pubCost;
    quantity = pubQuantity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked to have it display correctly, now i just need it to show the values. I get all zeroes

Comment: @Kyle Where do you get all zeroes? Can you edit your question to show the output you are getting?

Comment: I added the output, it's at the bottom of the question

Comment: @Kyle did you get your output fixed?

Comment: no i did not. i added the constructor and get/set methods to the question. That might have something to do with it. Those things always get my confused

Comment: @Kyle I edited my answer, let me know if it solves your output problem or not. Code I used for testing is here: https://ideone.com/xpVzet

Comment: That did not work, adding the .this. All of my variables are now public as well.